# Query execution is running indefinitely but not giving results

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, error-handling, transactions

I'm trying to learn error handling and i made this stored procedure for updation of data and the Stored Procedure is created successfully but execution takes very long time.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[uspUpdateData]
@CUST_CITY varchar(50)
as 
begin
begin try
begin transaction
update [dbo].[employee]
set CUST_CITY=@CUST_CITY 
COMMIT TRANSACTION
end try
begin catch
rollback transaction
END CATCH
END
GO
```

I have looked everywhere but this issue still persist
edit:runs indefinitely means its execution loading.

Comment: i'm guessing you already have an open transaction against the table, so it's blocking. Check EXEC sp_who2 to see if there's some blockage going on

Comment: Another way is to run: DBCC OPENTRAN ; and check the messages, it will print if there's a transaction going on

Comment: Get [sp_whoisactive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/releases)

Comment: As a side note: this error handling is really poor, and will just result in errors being swallowed. Since you only have one statement you don't need an explicit transaction anyway. And even if you did you don't need to roll it back yourself, instead just put `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the top and rollbacks will happen automatically. See also [What is the point of TRY CATCH block when XACT_ABORT is turned ON?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/306870/220697) And if you really *do* need to use `CATCH` make sure to use `THROW;` at the end of it in order to rethrow the original exception.

Answer (score -3):

Rewrited with indentation and ending code with ";" :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[uspUpdateData] 
   @CUST_CITY varchar(50) 
as 
begin 
   begin try 
      begin transaction; 
      update [dbo].[employee] 
      set CUST_CITY=@CUST_CITY; 
      COMMIT TRANSACTION; 
   end try 
   begin catch 
      rollback transaction; 
   end catch
END 
GO
```

There is no reason that this query runs indefinitely...